# No route match in controller spec for my complex route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, routes

I have this route:

```
resources :items, path: 'feed', only: [:index], defaults: { variant: :feed }
```

which is nested in the api and v1 namespaces. (the request_source params comes from the Api namespace).

I want to test the index action in my controller spec. I tried:

```
get :feed, community_id: community.id, :request_source=>"api"
```

does not work, and so does:

```
get :index, community_id: community.id, :request_source=>"api", variant: 'feed'
```

saying:

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:community_id=>"14", :request_source=>"api", :variant=>"feed", :controller=>"api/v1/items"}
```

-------EDIT---------

The reason why I want to use the variant to send the params to the controller is because I have all these routes:

```
    resources :items, path: 'feed',    only: [:index], defaults: { variant: 'feed' }
    resources :items, path: 'popular', only: [:index], defaults: { variant: 'popular' }
```

Then, in ItemsController, I have a before filter "get_items" for the index action wich does:

```
def get_items
  if params[:variant] == 'feed'
     ....
elsif params[:variant] == 'popular'
    ....
end
```

Comment: What's the backtrace on the exception?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is coming from defining `defaults: { variant: :feed }`. Could you please elaborate what you are attempting to accomplish with that.

I created an application to test what you have and with the following in `config/routes.rb`

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :items, path: 'feed', only: :index
  end
end
```

I got this when I ran `rake routes`.

```
$ rake routes
api_v1_items GET /api/v1/feed(.:format) api/v1/items#index
```

**Update:** to set a default for the `params` variable for something that isn't defined in the route you can use in your action.

```
params[:variant] ||= 'feed'
```

**Update 2:** you can conditionally assign `params[:variant]` in a before filter like so.

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_variant

  # or more simply
  # before_filter lambda { params[:variant] ||= 'feed' }

  def index
    render text: params[:variant]
  end

private      

  def get_variant
    # make sure we have a default variant set
    params[:variant] ||= 'feed'
  end
end
```

Comment: We have many routes going to items#index. default: { variant: :xxx } is used to set a params which will determine the behaviour of the index action based on the requested route.

Comment: @Alain it looks like the `defaults` hash is designed to set defaults for route parameters. Such as `:id` or `:format`. See my update

Comment: thing is, we have 3 routes: feed, popular and index which all use the exact same code (the one from index), we just have to do some setup before executing the index action in a before filter which looks at the :variant param. This allows us to reuse the index action without having to write any additional code in the controller. Like we would have had to do if we created each route and add code in each controller action to render the index page. If you are telling me there is no way to make this route work, I will wait a few days (hoping you are wrong! ;-) ) then give you the bounty.

Comment: @Alain I understand you want to wait, I'm interested to see if you can set default `params` from a route as well. However, just to let you know, it is possible to conditionally set `params` in a `before_filter`. See my second update.

Answer (score 0):

An idea I had to set a default variant might be to allow the path to be dynamic. Instead of setting `variant` as a query string use it as part of the actual path itself. This method will not require a before filter in your controller.

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    root :to => 'items#index', :defaults => { :variant => 'feed' }
    get ':variant' => 'items#index', :defaults => { :variant => 'feed' }
  end
end
```

Then you could access the different areas on the site with

```
GET "http://localhost:3000/api/v1" # params[:variant] == 'feed'
GET "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/feed" # params[:variant] == 'feed'
GET "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/popular" # params[:variant] == 'popular'
```